# Scrot command from rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to develop a rails application in which it takes the screen shot of the desktop every minute. I searched internet I couldn’t find any gem file related to this task.

So when I searched for taking screen shots I got a command scrot. Which when executed in command line it would take the screen shots. But problem is my Ruby file doesn't recognise the scrot command.

Is there any method to execute scrot command from Ruby file? Is there any gem file for this function?

I know when I can execute `scrot` command from Ruby. Then making it to crontab would solve my problem.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 as my OS.

This is my TestsController where I need to execute that command

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController

    require 'fileutils'
    include FileUtils

    def link
        return "http://" + root_domain 
    end


    def new
        puts pwd()
        result = scrot()
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean with _my ruby file doesn't recognise the scrot command_? Please post a reproducible failing code. And, which OS are you using?

Comment: sorry I am using Ubuntu 13.04. In which there is an extra application called scrot which will take the screen shots of my screen.scrot command running successfully in command line.But not in ruby file.

Comment: You should provide a code example too, otherwise it is hard to guess which is the error and thus to provide a pertinent answer

Comment: Thank you, now we have some necessary informations in order to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are new to Ruby (which is not a crime ;-) ).

In Ruby, shell commands are not callable using functions; there are some special syntaxes:

```
`echo hello`
#=> hello
%x{echo hello}
#=> hello
```

`pwd()` works just because it is a Ruby function implemented inside irb; indeed it works only inside irb (unless you don't implement ir, or you require a library which implements it).

So, in order to run `scrot` as shell command you should write

```
def new
  result = `scrot` # or
  result = %x{scrot}
end
```

Comment: yes I am new to rails This is my first project rails

Answer (score 0):

You can run any arbitrary code from a ruby script by including it with backticks

Scrot is a command line library written in C, so it won't run in ruby, you'll need to do somthing like

```
result = `you scrot command` 
#use result how you would like
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but undefined method `scrot' for #<TestsController:0x007fe2c4c74120> error is generating. Does I need to include any files other than FileUtils to get it.